# problems with ascii conversion java

Tags: java, ascii

hey so I have a problem with typecasting int. I have a program here designed to print the two digits of an entered number then I am supposed to increment the first digit using the ++ operator and multiply by ten then add the second digit and print the new number (which should be the original plus 10). I can't get the first digit to increment correctly because of ascii.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Lab1_Redo
     {

        public static void main (String[] args) 
        {
            int Zero = (char)0;

            Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a two-digit number:");
            String entered_digits = Keyboard.nextLine();
            int FirstDigit = entered_digits.charAt(0);
            System.out.println("The first digit that was entered was:" + " " + (char)FirstDigit);
            int SecondDigit = entered_digits.charAt(1);
            System.out.println("The second digit that was entered was:" + " " + (char)SecondDigit);
             int AsciiToInt = FirstDigit;
             AsciiToInt++;
             int SecondDigits = (char)SecondDigit;
             int EnteredNumberPlusTen = ((AsciiToInt * 10) + SecondDigits);
             //System.out.println("This new number:" + " " + EnteredNumberPlusTen + " " + "Is the original number plus ten");
            System.out.println(AsciiToInt);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int AsciiToInt = FirstDigit - '0';
int digit2 = SecondDigit - '0';
```

Unless you have a particular reason to manipulate the input character by character, you should just do:

```
int input = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
input += 10;
```

Comment: I used that first code snip that you posted. The second line contains code we haven't covered in class so I can't use it. Thanks for your help. Does subtracting '0' from a character value always give you the int value of the character you are subtracting it from?

Comment: Yes, as long as it is a digit and you are using ASCII (or Unicode). You will be able to see why if you look at an ascii table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Interger.parseInt(String string)` to convert strings to int.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Answer (score 0):

When you assign the char to an int, it will take the ASCII value.
Try the following code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab1_Redo{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int Zero = (char)0;
    Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a two-digit number:");
    String entered_digits = Keyboard.nextLine();
    int FirstDigit = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(entered_digits.charAt(0)));
    System.out.println("The first digit that was entered was:" + " " + FirstDigit);
    int SecondDigit =  Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(entered_digits.charAt(1)));
    System.out.println("The second digit that was entered was:" + " " + SecondDigit);
    int EnteredNumberPlusTen = ((++FirstDigit * 10) + SecondDigit);
    System.out.println(EnteredNumberPlusTen);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Lab1_Redo
     {

        public static void main (String[] args) 
        {             

            Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a two-digit number:");
            String entered_digits = Keyboard.nextLine();
              char sr[] = entered_digits.toCharArray();
            int FirstDigit = (int) sr[0];
            System.out.println("The first digit that was entered was:" + " " + sr[0]);
            int SecondDigit = (int) sr[1];
            System.out.println("The second digit that was entered was:" + " " + sr[1]);
             int AsciiToInt = FirstDigit;
             AsciiToInt++;
             int SecondDigits = (char)SecondDigit;
             int EnteredNumberPlusTen = ((AsciiToInt * 10) + SecondDigits);
             //System.out.println("This new number:" + " " + EnteredNumberPlusTen + " " + "Is the original number plus ten");
            System.out.println(AsciiToInt);
        }
    }
```

try this one..!

Comment: First...you will need to actually try it. Fix it so it actually works. Good method though.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting wrong number because you are not subtracting 48 from the ascii value. 0's ascii value is 48 so you can not simply type cast to int and use. You have to subtract it. Code is valid if only 2 digit number is present.

**Modified Code :**

```
            Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a two-digit number:");
            String entered_digits = Keyboard.nextLine();
            int FirstDigit = entered_digits.charAt(0) - 48;
            System.out.println("The first digit that was entered was:" + " " + FirstDigit);
            int SecondDigit = entered_digits.charAt(1) - 48;
            System.out.println("The second digit that was entered was:" + " " + SecondDigit);
            int EnteredNumberPlusTen = ((++FirstDigit * 10) + SecondDigit);
            System.out.println("This new number:" + " " + EnteredNumberPlusTen + " " + "Is the original number plus ten");
```

**Optimal Code :**

```
        Integer number = Keyboard.nextInt();
        int first = number /10;
        int second = number%10;
        EnteredNumberPlusTen = ((++first * 10) + second);
        System.out.println("This new number:" + " " + EnteredNumberPlusTen + " " + "Is the original number plus ten");
```

Comment: Nice concept but isn't 48 a Magic Number?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it's because your dealing with the represented ASCII value for each parsed digit of the supplied two digit numerical *STRING*.

Let's supply a value of **65** .....

Because you're using the **String.charAt()** method you will need to go a little further to actually convert that parsed out digit into a Integer value. Because you coded:

```
int FirstDigit = entered_digits.charAt(0);
```

this will place the value of 54 into the ***FirstDigit*** integer variable which is actually the ASCII value for the Ascii character **6**. This is obviously not what you want. What you really want is the integer value of **6** placed into the ***FirstDigit*** integer variable and to do this you will need to convert the character **6** to a String and then convert the numerical string to a Integer value like this:

```
String firstNumber = String.valueOf(entered_digits.charAt(0));
int FirstDigit = Integer.valueOf(firstNumber);
System.out.println("The first digit that was entered was:" + " " + firstNumber);
```

Now you are actually dealing with the integer representation of the numerical string "**6**". Do the very same thing for your second digit as well and you're off to the races.

**Tip:** After doing the above you no longer need the code line:

```
int SecondDigits = (char)SecondDigit;
```

Make the necessary modifications....

**Tip:** You can also use the **String.substring()** method instead of the **String.charAt()** method. With Java there is always more than one way to skin a cat, or beaver, or whatever.